# Is a UK visa issued to a person or passport?

Tags: uk

My wife and I are recently married and we applied successfully for a tourist visa to the UK. This visa has been issued on her passport that is under her maiden name.

We still have some time left before travel so we thought we might like to change my wife's passport to her married surname. This would of course result in cancellation of the passport in the maiden name with the visa inside it.

If she now attempts to travel to the UK with both passports and originals of the pertinent documentszwill it be legitimately explainable and accepted by the immigration officers en route i.e. Philippines and UK?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp/youre-outside-the-uk

Comment: @HankyPanky that's an answer ! Add, ping me, I'll upvote !!!